# What does EOL mean?

Tags: word-usage

In a list of professors in a University's prospectus I found the acronym EOL.

> [image: Screenshot of staff list]

After some repeated web search I found nothing strongly related but a list of full-forms on [thefreedictionary.com](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/EOL) and the only phrase that can be of some relation is '*End of Lecture*'. I didn't have much luck with Google on the usage of '*End of Lecture*' either.

Summing up, what's the full form of EOL in this context.

Comment: Extra-Ordinary Leave?

Comment: @PeterShor Your comment was posted earlier than my answer. Would you care to submit yours as an answer? I've deleted mine in the meantime.

Comment: @Lawrence: Go ahead and undelete your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to address non-standard (even on the Indian subcontinent) in-certain-houses usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Western tech industry, you most frequently encounter the term *EOL* for software that’s reached its [**end of life**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product)). It is occasionally used for the same in health care for the dying.

But on the Indian subcontinent, it apparently refers to one of a ***great*** many forms of leave to which various public employees are entitled.  From [this document](https://www.nitt.edu/www/uploads/684_leaverulesv2.pdf) from the National Institute of Technology at Tiruchirappalli we learn of just a few of these many, many leaves:

1. Casual Leave. (CL)
2. Special Casual Leave.(SCL)
3. Special Leave
4. Earned Leave (EL)
5. Vacation (Only for academic staff)
6. Half Pay Leave (HPL)
7. Commuted Leave
8. Leave Not Due (LND)
9. **Extra-ordinary Leave (EOL)**
10. Maternity Leave
11. Adoption Leave
12. Paternity Leave
13. Hospital Leave
14. Sabbatical Leave
15. Study Leave

<sup>(*Isn't that remarkable?*)</sup>

So probably this is a professor currently on extraördinary leave, for whatever reason. The linked-to document explains what this is at great length, the beginning of which runs:

> Extraordinary Leave shall always be without leave salary and may be granted when no other kind of leave is admissible, or when other leave being admissible, the staff concerned has specifically applied in writing for the grant of EOL.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the context, I'd suggest it stands for *Extra Ordinary Leave*.

> 8. Extra Ordinary Leave :- Extraordinary leave is granted to a Government servant when no other leave is admissible or when other leave is admissible, but the Government servant applies in writing for extraordinary leave.
>      [- G Connect](http://www.gconnect.in/orders-in-brief/types-of-leave-available-to-central-govt-employees.html)